# Redmine_RE plugin is not saving the data

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

i am using the Redmine.3.1.0.Then i have installed redmine_re plugin.But when i try to save the requirement using the Redmine_re plugin i am getting the following error

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `connection' for #<ReArtifactRelationship:0x800ddb0>):
  lib/plugins/acts_as_list/lib/active_record/acts/list.rb:220:in `bottom_item'
  lib/plugins/acts_as_list/lib/active_record/acts/list.rb:214:in `bottom_position_in_list'
  lib/plugins/acts_as_list/lib/active_record/acts/list.rb:205:in `add_to_list_bottom'
  lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in `sudo_mode'
```

pls suggest how to resolve this error
@ste26054

Answer (score 1):

I did not develop this plugin, but I think the support for redmine 3.1.0 is only partial at the moment. (And you may get other errors even after fixing this).

I believe you are getting an error because of this: [Deprecate #connection in favour of accessing it via the class](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/992d87db02507363a4ad4ab40a3e4c4b32cf0408)

And your error is related to [this file](https://github.com/tmerten/redmine_re/blob/2347931e7a2c8e6d635571c126cfcf8bbdcf19e2/app/models/re_artifact_relationship.rb#L62):

In this method:

```
def scope_condition()
    "#{connection.quote_column_name("source_id")} = #{quote_value(self.source_id)}
    AND
    #{connection.quote_column_name("relation_type")} = #{quote_value(self.relation_type)}"
end
```

Try to add `self.class.` in front of `connection`

You may have to repeat this for other files in the code.

If your changes are working, I would suggest you to submit a pull request on their plugin github page :)